# Macbook Pro doesn't recognize password until reset

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

For some reason my OSX El Capitain Macbook Pro has started to not accept my password until I hold down the power button and restart it. Then it accepts the password just fine.

Any ideas what might be going on/how to prevent that from happening? It's kind of annoying to have to restart the computer constantly...

Answer (score 1):

Start in Safe Mode (holding shift key). When fully started (takes some time), restart normally.
If that is not enough do the old Mac witchcraft, SMC and Pram reset.